# In this dockerfile , When i build and run the image nginx is up and running but sensu-agent is not running. i need to start is manually

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, sensu

```
`
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl jq bash  
# Install Nginx
RUN apt-get install -y nginx

# Install Sensu agent from the official repository
RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/sensu/stable/script.deb.sh | bash \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y sensu-go-agent

COPY agent.yaml /etc/sensu/agent.yaml

# Define environment variables for Sensu backend connection
ENV SENSU_BACKEND_URL=ws://34.207.219.74:8081
ENV SENSU_SUBSCRIPTIONS=linux,system

# Expose Nginx ports
EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "nginx -g 'daemon off;' & sensu-agent start"]

`
```

In this dockerfile ,  When i build and run the image nginx is up and running but sensu-agent is not running.  i need to start is manually.

Comment: A Docker container normally only runs a single process.  You should run this agent in a separate container.

Answer (score 0):

For complex entrypoint scenarios, it's useful for the entrypoint to be `bash entrypoint.sh` and do all your complex logix there.